# wrong URLs deploying to a subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger, dragonfly-gem

in my view I have:

```
<a href="<%= @project.file.url %>"><%= @project.file.name %></a>
```

locally, in development, all works fine and I can download the file. But on my VPS in production I get a 404:

```
[Mon Nov 05 18:28:40 2012] [error] [client 88.7.246.152] File does not exist: 
  /srv/http/media, referer: http://www.stanosas.it/copisteria/projects/1
```

no trace in `log/production.log`

`link_to` works fine.

here is my Apache (Passenger) setup https://gist.github.com/4018657

I access my app in a subfolder like `www.myapp.com/copisteria`

here is `config/initializers/dragonfly.rb` https://github.com/enricostano/copisteria/blob/master/config/initializers/dragonfly.rb

here is `config/application.rb` https://github.com/enricostano/copisteria/blob/master/config/application.rb

any hint?

EDIT: It seems that Apache or Passenger doesn't recognize the subdirectory in URLs.

Comment: Some debugging tips: 


Try accessing or doing a wget for that particular url from your production server. Is it accessible? There may be some firewall rules to prevent that.

Inspect the view using firebug and see what the url is. Is it absolute, or relative? Is it as expected?

Comment: in the HTML I have `<a href="/media/BAhbBlsHOgZmSSJTMjAxMi8xMS8wNi8xN180OF8xMF83MzVfQnJlYWtpbmcuQmFkLlMwNUUwOC5IRFRWLngyNjRfQVNBUC5fd3d3LkVOR1NVQi5ORVQuemlwBjoGRVQ">filename.zip</a>`

Comment: I just realized that the URL is `www.mysite.it/media/etcetc` while it should be `www.mysite.it/copisteria/media/etcetc`. But this happens only for that link, other links works fine. I'll add another relative link by hand in the view to see what Apache understand...

Comment: <%= @project.file.url %> In that case the url method for your file object (model) is generating the wrong url. Try looking at that function.

Comment: @amit_saxena `@project.file.url` is the way to call URLs for DragonFly objects. And it works deploying the app outside a subdirectory. I think it's more an Apache/Passenger issue. http://markevans.github.com/dragonfly/file.URLs.html